# Data Prediction Models

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, predictive-models, model

I'm working on a project which request to develop a model to forecast the rental demand of Bike sharing company on January 2017, which will be then be compared with the actual demand, the details are shown below:

The data is: excel sheet of hourly rental data of 2015-2016. classified by Two types of rental: casual renters and registered renters.
The spreadsheet also records the weather condition in each hour (e.g., temperature, wind speed and humidity).

Sample of the data:

[image: 2015-2016 Data]

The request is to fill testing worksheet of January 2017 as below:

[image: January Prediction Data]

I've start working on the this using ARIMA & SARIMA model in Python, however, it wouldn't work since it is hourly renting.

Could you please advise me of the best model I should work on it to predict the rental demand? and in which language?

Thank you!